# Python - Simple tkinter menu

Tags: python, menu, tkinter

I need help from you.

I want to code a simple menu with tkinter, but i have problem with that.
What I want to do -  In my menu,there are 2 items: "first", "second". When i click on the first, program must write 'The first' and then when I click on the second, it must write second, but the first one there will be not yet.

Can anybody help me? Thx.

I mean something like this

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

def do_something():
    # this function e.g. write 'The first'
    pass

def do_something_other():  
    # this function e.g. write 'The second' (but 'The first' there will be not yet)

main_menu = Menu(root)
root["menu"] = main_menu    

submenu1 = Menu(main_menu)   
submenu1.add_command(label="Item1", command=do_something)
submenu1.add_command(label="Item2", command=do_something_other)

main_menu.add_cascade(label="Program", menu=submenu1)
```

My goal is, that the canvas will be changing after clicking on the Item1/Item2

Comment: Can you please share the code you've already done?

Comment: The problem is, that i don´t have any code, which works how i want.

Comment: So... You need a Tkinter tutorial? [here you go](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/).

Comment: Can you clarify this: "(but 'The first' there will be not yet)"

Comment: I thought, that there will be written only 'The second'.

Comment: I would recommend looking up youtube tutorials by a channel called thenewboston: he's put up several really good tkinter tutorials, including one on menus (which would be easy to apply to your own problem) as well as related menu-stuff stuff like toolbars. This was 2 years ago, but I recommend it anyway if you're planning to revisit/learn more stuff about tkinter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Tkinter [`Label`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/label.htm) widget to display text in your GUI. The `Label` widget has a method called [`config`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/label.htm#Tkinter.Label.config-method) that you can use to access options of the widget, to include its `text` attribute.

Here's a simple example. You'll have to modify it to work with your menus and specific needs:

```
root = Tk()

def callback():                       # this function will access the
    label.config(text='Updated Text') # config method of label to change it

label = Label(root, text='Original text') # make the label and set default text
btn = Button(root, text='Change text', command=callback) # make the button, which executes the callback func

label.pack()
btn.pack()

mainloop()
```